# Default values for variable stored in SRAM

Tags: c, stm32, sections

We are having some troubles with variables stored in SRAM and default values.

We are working with a STM32F745ZE micro. We had to define a section for SRAM:

```
/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
ITCM_RAM (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 16K   /* +MW+ */
/*RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 319K*/
RAM (xrw)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 64K   /* +MW+ DTCM RAM */
RAM_GEN (xrw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20010000, LENGTH = 255K  /* +MW+ SRAM1 + SRAM2 */

TRACER (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x2004FC00, LENGTH = 1K    /* +MW+ TRACER memory space */
FLASH (rx)     : ORIGIN =  0x8000000, LENGTH = 512K
}
```

(...)

```
  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >RAM

  /* +MW+ SRAM data section */
  .ram_gen :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sram_gen = .;     /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.ram_gen)        /* .data sections */
    *(.ram_gen*)       /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _eram_gen = .;     /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM_GEN
```

We want to assign default values to some varieables. It works fine for variables not stored in SRAM, but it doesn't work for varaibles stored in SRAM:. Example

```
static Test_Ram_t testRam = { .value = 1 };
static Test_Ram_Value_t testRamValue __attribute__((section(".ram_gen"))) = { .value = 1 };

static void Test_Ram_Task1(void const *pvParameters)
{
    Test_Ram_Printf("Test Ram: START -----------------------------------------------");
    Test_Ram_Printf("Test Ram: Pre value: %d %d", testRam.value, testRamValue.value);

    testRam.value += 10;
    testRamValue.value += 10;

    Test_Ram_Printf("Test Ram: Post value: %d %d", testRam.value, testRamValue.value);

    osDelay(osWaitForever);
}
```

If we reboot the application 3 times the application output is:

```
[10:30:25.002]
[10:30:25.004] Test Ram: START -----------------------------------------------
[10:30:25.005] Test Ram: Pre value: 1 1
[10:30:25.005] Test Ram: Post value: 11 11
[10:30:27.599]
[10:30:27.601] Test Ram: START -----------------------------------------------
[10:30:27.603] Test Ram: Pre value: 1 11
[10:30:27.604] Test Ram: Post value: 11 21
[10:30:29.497]
[10:30:29.500] Test Ram: START -----------------------------------------------
[10:30:29.502] Test Ram: Pre value: 1 21
[10:30:29.503] Test Ram: Post value: 11 31
```

Varaible `testRam`, stored in RAM, is assigned the default value in every restart, but varaible `testRamValue`, stored in SRAM, the value is  keeped between reboots.

Does anyone know how to force to assign the default value on every reboot?

Comment: Isn't the whole point of SRAM of *keeping* the values?!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala No, SRAM isn't supposed to retain values when the power is cut. It just doesn't need to refresh the contents of cells periodically, unlike DRAM.

Comment: When do you initialize SRAM, is it before the loops that initialized `.bss` and `.data`? These functions run well before `main`. Search for `__initialize_hardware_early` (at least that's the name of a function generated by CubeMX a while ago), you may also want to check `_start` function inside `_startup.c` and see the order in which things are initialized.

Comment: You need to add your own start-up code to initialize another .data segments. They will not be "magically" initialized without it

Comment: BTW you need to show in  the linker script  that the data is stored in flash.

Comment: @P__J__ and @JacekŚlimok Thanks. The code is in `startup_stm32f745xx.s` file. I'll look how to set the default values in a new .data section.